# How can I exclude attributes from associations when using deep_cloneable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deep-copy, cloneable

I am using [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) gem. I can do deep copying of the association, and also I can exclude the attributes from the parent object. But is there a way to exclude the attributes even from the associations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can explicitly exclude attributes from the parent or the association or both. Here's an example directly from the docs:

```
pirate.dup :include => :parrot, :except => [:name, { :parrot => [:name] }]
```

For your case, you'll want to leave off the :name of the parent like this:

```
pirate.dup :include => :parrot, :except => [{ :parrot => [:name] }]
```

As an aside, you can also include attributes from just the association, which could serve your needs just fine if you want to use a whitelisting technique. This is the example directly from the docs:

```
pirate.dup :include => :parrot, :only => [:name, { :parrot => [:name] }]
```

What you probably want to do for whitelisting is this:

```
pirate.dup :include => :parrot, :only => [{ :parrot => [:name] }]
```

Hope this helps!